# Magento 2: How to check if checkout payment page

Tags: magento2, url, payment

I'm looking on how to check if i'm standing at checkout **payment** page, which have url "`fudu.magento.net/checkout/#payment`" by php or by js.
I was trying to use to get url, but it always return `checkout_index_index`
To be clear, i want to compare between **shipping** page and **payment** page, which have url is "**checkout/#shipping**" and "**checkout/#payment**".

EDIT 1: I've trying using script to check css display:none of #shipping, but it doesn't work either, because when i click "next" in **shipping** page, it will not render any js out after that.

> my js code:

```
function checkIfPaymentPage(){
                if($('#shipping').css('display') == 'none'){
                    console.log('worked');
                }
            }
```

After i click "next", nothing appear in inspect console:

[image]

EDIT 1:

I'm using  `window.setInterval(function(){ //code }, 3000);` and it worked for me to testing, but i don't thing this is the best practice, so if you guys have any other solutions, please tell me :)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: In which file you want to check ?

Comment: I want to check it in my custom phtml file, or Block, or Helper, anything that can check it :) Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer. Maybe it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get checkout page url, try this:

```
<?php echo $block->getUrl('checkout', ['_secure' => true]);?>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Doesn't work, i var_dump it and got this `string(57) "http://fudu.magento.net/index.php/checkout/"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
 $uri = $block->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
  echo $uri;
```